# SSH server on Shield w/Android 11

Tags: android-11, ssh

I recently purchased a Shield running Android 11.  I want to enable an SSH server on this box.

I tried an SSHd app from the play store but it didn't seem to work.  Looking at the websites for a couple of SSHd packages I see lots of warnings that SSH daemons will stop working as of Android 10.

Does that mean SSHd is no longer available on Android 11?  Is it possible to add/enable an SSHd service on a non-rooted android 11 box?

Comment: Android never had an ssh server integrated. As you already mentioned apps can start an ssh server but newer Android versions have some major changes you need to address in an app. Most likely those apps are simply not updated for Android 10+. You can simply test Termux + sshd if it works (this should be the best maintained way) https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Android 10 brought some substantial privacy changes, like the restriction of access to the /proc/net/ filesystem, which contained info about the device's network state.

So even if you were to simulate Root access with Termux you wouldn't be able to get the IP of your SSH.

As of now, your only option is to get a phone with Android 9 or lower or root your phone.